# preg_replace not working for mobile number format

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a simple script to format the number (to remove `0`s after dialing code)

```
$dialingCode = '971';
$mobileNo    = '9710521666038';
// Remove 0 after dialingCode
echo preg_replace('/^(' . $dialingCode .')(.*?)/', $dialingCode . "$2", $mobileNo);
```

But it's returning `9710521666038`.

The expected output is `971521666038`

Comment: Use `^(971)0*` instead.

Comment: I see you are still using `(.*?)` at the end. That makes no sense since `.*?` at the end of regex always matches an empty string.

Comment: Isn't this question answered well enough? Also, you may use  `preg_replace('/^(' . preg_quote($dialingCode, '/') .')0+/', '$1', $mobileNo);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to capture anything:

```
preg_replace('/^' . $dialingCode . '\K0*/', '', $mobileNo);
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/ZrSmR)

Comment: What does \K0 does?

Comment: `\K` tells engine to forget whatever it has consumed. `0*` means match following zeros if they exist.

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/^966\K0*/', '', "966‭0530345570‬");` -> doesn't work

Comment: There is a hidden character (in hex `\x202d`) between `6` and `0` that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use preg_match and use `0*` to match zero or more zeros.
Then implode the two captures to get the phone number.

```
$mobileNo    = '9710521666038';

Preg_match("/^(971)0*(\d+)/", $mobileNo, $match);

Echo implode("", array_slice($match,1));
```

https://3v4l.org/5AmCR

Answer (score 1):

You could use `0?` outside the capture group:

```
$dialingCode = '971';
$mobileNo    = '9710521666038';
// Remove 0 after dialingCode
echo preg_replace('/^(971)0?(.*?)/', '971' . "$2", $mobileNo);
```

Output:

```
971521666038
```

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/^(966)0*(\d+)/', '966' . "$2", '966‭0530345570‬');` -> doesn't work

Comment: As pointed out by revo, your string is not 13 bytes length. This works for "this string", `preg_replace('/^(966)\W*0?(\d+)/', '966' . "$2", '966‭0530345570‬');`.